# How could I format this data in this way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

### It's nested comments data, I just want to make the data in this format.

Please help me get the better-optimized function which could convert the array to be the structured array as shown below.
`raw data`

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : 2
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : 1
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : 1
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    }
]
```

`formatted data`

```js
let structredData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null,
        children : [
             {
                id: 4,
                text : "Hello world",
                parent : 1
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                text : "Hello world",
                parent : 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null,
        children : [
            {
                id: 3,
                text : "Hello world",
                parent : 2
            } 
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    }
]
```

I just wanted to implement a nested comment feature in my web app, so I thought it could be much easier if I structured the data in this format. Please also let me know what could be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first filter out the items using `Array#filter`, which don't have a parent as these are the items we need to keep in the final array.

Then map those to their children using `Array#find` and add a `children` property in each item:

```js
const mapToChild = (data) => {
     return data
     .filter(i => !i.parent)
     .map(d => {
       let children;
       if(!d.parent){
        children = data.filter(i => i.parent === d.id);
       }
       return children && children.length ? {...d, children} : d;
     });
 }

const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : 2
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : 1
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : 1
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    }
];

console.log(mapToChild(data));
```

### Edited to handle nested children:

We can use `Array#reduce` when we have to take care of nested children:

```js
const mapToChild = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((r, o) => {
    const children = data.filter(i => i.parent == o.id);
    if(children && children.length) {
      o.children = children;
    }
    !o.parent && r.push(o);
    return r;
  }, []);
}
const data = [
    {
        id: 2,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : null
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : 2
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text : "Hello world",
        parent : 3
    }
];
console.log(mapToChild(data));
```

Comment: In case if I want to do with more nested data, then

Comment: @ManasPaul how exactly? you can follow the same principle though

Comment: For example another nested or more https://pastebin.com/Cumz0pNp

Comment: @ManasPaul please accept and upvote, if my answer helped